# How to get all ungrouped items with distinct-values() in XQuery?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

With this XQuery expression

```
for $ex in distinct-values(//products/product/@group)
return $ex
```

and this XML

```
<xml>
    <products>
        <product id="10" group="2"></product>
        <product id="20" group="1"></product>
        <product id="25" group=""></product>
        <product id="30" group="2"></product>
        <product id="35" group=""></product>
    </products>
</xml>
```

I'm getting only:

- product group '2'
- product group '1'

But I also need:

- product group '' (@id=25)
- product group '' (@id=35)

**Expecting (order not of interest):**

Only 1 product (the first if more than 1 with the same group) of a group and also every product with no group.

- product id 10 with group '2'
- product id 20 with group '1'
- product id 35 with group ''
- product id 25 with group ''

Every product with an empty group should also be returned in this xquery, but how?

Comment: What do you mean... did you get only two values ('2' & '1') returned by using that query, while the expected return value are 3 values ('2', '1' & '')?

Comment: @har07 i'm receiving 2 products (with value 2 and 1), but i need 4 (including the both products who has no group)

Comment: @har07 updatet the question for the expectation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also the empty string is a distinct value and should be returned already, but likely you're simply not observing it. Changing your query to

```
for $ex in distinct-values(//products/product/@group)
return <value>{ $ex }</value>
```

you will get a result like

```
<value>2</value>
<value>1</value>
<value/>
```

(while `<value/>` is equivalent to `<value></value>`, and "contains" the empty string).

If you want to match both a single product for empty groups and all products without a group, you can for example split apart the query in two parts: filtering for products with groups, and then adding those without.

```
(
  (: return first product for each product group :)
  for $group in distinct-values(//products/product/@group)
  (: unless group is empty :)
  where $group
  return (//product[@group eq $group])[1],
  (: add products without any group :)
  //product[@group eq '']
)
```

Comment: Thats pretty nice, I updated my question what my result expectation looks like. Maybe you can help me getting both products with empty groups there too?

Comment: this is amazin,  thank you for the explanation and your time

Comment: does that mean that first every product with a group comes and afterwards every product with no group? how to order it if we have an attribute named `order` e.g. `<product id="25" order="1">` ?

Comment: Wrap in another flwor expression and user `order by`.

Answer (score 1):

Xpath 1.0 gives an ability to find this elements without any program code

```
//product[
  not(@group = preceding-sibling::product/@group) 
  or (@group="")
  ]
```

Comment: Without any clever optimizations, this will result in quadratic runtime. Using `distinct-values` can result in linear runtime if implemented reasonably. Using XQuery 3.0's `group by` featuers might work out even faster, if performance is important, as the grouping is implemented in compiled code, not evaluated XQuery.

Comment: I agree with you. I always consider Xpath as an extreme option because  it is very expansive. But the logic of his expressions I really like. And what is about the answer  - it's just a different approach to solving

Comment: @splash58  
does that mean that first every product with a group comes and afterwards every product with no group? how to order it if we have an attribute named order e.g. <product id="25" order="1">

Comment: Xpath can't to change order of output. It only select elements which satisfy a condition